# Get name of map-loop-element when looping over tibble columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to extract the column name of the current column when looping with map. For example, I would like to un-do the scaling if some variables:

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble(a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = runif(10))
l <- list(a = list(min = -19, max = 20), b = list(min = 22, max = 55), c = list(min = 80, max = 120))
restore <- function(x, r) x * (r$max - r$min) + r$min
my_cols <- c("a", "c")
d %>%
  select(!!!my_cols) %>%
  map(~restore(.x, l[[name(.x)]]))
# Error in name(.x) : could not find function "name"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy with `imap` from `purrr`.

Note that when using the formula shortcut, the first argument is the value (`.x`), and the second is the position/name (`.y`).

See the help page on `imap` for more details. But essentially if the object you are iterating over has names, then the second argument (`.y`) to the function is the name (otherwise it's the position).

```r
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = runif(10))
l <- list(a = list(min = -19, max = 20), b = list(min = 22, max = 55), c = list(min = 80, max = 120))
restore <- function(x, r) x * (r$max - r$min) + r$min
my_cols <- c("a", "c")
d %>%
  select(!!!my_cols) %>%
  imap(~restore(.x, l[[.y]]))
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, why is `.y` the name of the column? (1st element is value, 2nd element of imap is the position, I am good if the order is the same?)